# Restricting files from Google Cloud Storage to the users that have authenticated with my Google App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE application with a database of users.

When one of the user tries to download, say, file `myapplication.appspot.com/somefile.jpg`, I would:

1. check on the GAE database whether he is allowed to
2. if he is allowed, redirect him to a cloud storage bucket of mine from where he can download `somefile.jpg`
3. if he is not allowed, return him a 404 error code, and do some magic so that directly trying to download `somefile.jpg` from the cloud storage bucket does not complete.

Now what’s unclear to me is how to control access to `somefile.jpg`. How can I restrict the download to this scope of users?

PS: using something else than Google Storage is not an option (for those of you guys who thought about blobstore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to restrict access on a per user basic you can restrict access on a per application (Google App Engine App) basis.
Every application has a service account, what you can do is set an ACL on the bucket to allow access to the application service account.

Now all you need to write an handler that would access Google Storage and return the data to the user.

Comment: Do you mean that the handler proxies the data on storage? That means the handler reads from storage and forwards the data to the user?

Comment: @nalply yes that's one way of doing so, another way will be to return a secure signed url that allow access to the data

Answer (score 3):

As Shay noted, every App Engine application automatically has associated with it an internal account, called the “service account”. Normally, the service account name follows the pattern “your-app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com”, however, you can confirm the exact name by visiting the [App Engine Administration Console](https://appengine.google.com/), then clicking on your app name, followed by the “Application Settings” link, at which point you should see your service account name.

Once you find your service account name, add it to the “Team” subpage on the [APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) with “Can edit” permissions. This is even easier than updating the bucket ACL because you don't have to change any ACLs, however, bear in mind this applies to all buckets in your project. If you'd like to restrict your app to only have access to a subset of the buckets owned by your project then you'll want to update the per-bucket ACL(s), as Shay proposed.

Comment: Ah yea, that’s even better (in my case, at least).